# How does the dual entry EVA work?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, rebuild-of-evangelion

In Evangellion 3.33,  Two entry plugs are inserted into EVA 13.

I thought the angle of the plugs looked like they would crash into each other within the EVA:

[image]

Having taken a screenshot I estimated the rough position of the placed plugs:
[image]

And my assumptions were correct. Clearly the two plugs would crash if this was correct. Is this merely an animation mistake, or is there something that happens to the plugs once they are inside an EVA as the cockpits look quite different inside?

Comment: There's nothing but speculation at this point. It's possible that the pink/red bits where the plugs enter (which are markedly different from the mechanical looking slots from before) actually take the entry plugs into some "meta" space (for lack of a better word) that's not entirely physical. It's possible that the plugs, in the angle from the screenshot above, are actually angled slightly forward and back so that they slide one in front of the other once they've reached the full depth. There's going to be a Groundworks released soon, maybe we'll get production drawings from that.

Comment: Yeah, so the first volume of Groundworks 3.0 has been released, but it looks like it ends before the dual entry system (looks like it ends where Shinji's going down into the crater the first time, sans Eva). So I guess we wait for next volume...

Comment: The second volume of Groundworks 3.0 is out, @JonLin. Do you (or EvaGeeks) have access to it?

Comment: Agreed; while the plugs are at the same angle on the vertical axis, the chutes most likely enter the EVA unit at somewhat different angles (which cannot be seen from a 2D frontal POV) so that front part of one plug actually rests some distance in front of the other plug. Remember that both plugs connect to the "cockpit" inside the EVA, which is used by both Shinji and Kaworu simultaneously.